# How to dockerise oracle client in windows docker container

Tags: flutter, oracle, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The oracle client image is not in docker hub. zip file is using while running to install the installation is not happening properly.

> Start-Process c:\oracle\setup\ODAC122010Xcopy_x64\setup.exe 
> -ArgumentList '-silent', '-nowait', '-waitforcompletion',
> '-responseFile', 'c:\oracle\setup\responsefile.rsp' \     -NoNewWindow
> -Wait

Comment: What do you mean by *is not happening properly*?